# Bootstrap Carousel Plotly Plots are not reponsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, plotly, bootstrap-5

The JS code and Carousel code are both from the official code. All I do was to replaced the `<img>` with `<div id="myDiv1">` (the Plotly plot object).

**The issue is only the parent (the first) plot is represented in the correct size. Others are not responsive.**

I tried to remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` on the HTML head and the pages worked well. However, I do need the auto scale function.

Please review the code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/zacksamber/pen/mdBELxR) and make your browser as phone size.

References:

- The JS code is from Plotly official sample: [Responsive / Fluid Layouts in JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/responsive-fluid-layout/)
- The Carousel code is from BootStrap v5.1 official sample: [Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/)

PS. `img` works well. Only the plotly objects are not responsive.